# How to stop application users from sharing database session context variables?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, connection-pooling, row-level-security

I'm working on a web application and we are making some changes to have Row-Level Security on certain tables. It's a Java app, we use a single database user for all application users, and we have a connection pool instead of manually opening/closing connections. Previously we were setting the session context variable once per user when a user logged in using the following stored procedure:

`EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = ‘...’, @value = ‘...’`

which caused an issue where if userA logged in and then userB logged in, userA was able to see userB's records, and unable to see it's own.

I easily fixed this by executing the above stored procedure every time a connection is obtained from the pool. However I'm concerned about a possible race condition:

1. userA performs an action that causes the app to interact with the database
2. app obtains a connection from the pool and sets the session context variable for userA
3. userB performs an action that causes another interaction with the database
4. app obtains a connection from the pool and sets the session context variable for userB
5. app uses the connection obtained in step 2 to fulfill userA's request, but uses userB's context

Given that the app I work on isn't really expected to have many concurrent users, I'm not extremely worried about this ever showing up in the wild, but it still concerns me, and I wonder if there's a better solution for this problem that I'm simply missing. So far the only other idea I have is creating a connection pool per user, but that seems like an overkill.

Comment: Unless you have a serious bug in your application code or connection pool that would lead a connection to be shared between two units of work, the scenario you propose shouldn't happen (and if it would happen, you would have even bigger problems beyond sessions sharing values).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so if I understand your comment correctly, you mean that if I set the session value on one connection, it shouldn't affect another connection from the same pool; which in turn means that the issue I was seeing before was not because all connections from the pool were affected by the value change, but rather that a user was being given a connection that had the value already set? I had originally assumed all connections from the pool were being affected since we were only setting the value once on login yet the original issue was pretty consistently reproducible.

Comment: My comment was from a perspective where you set those variables when you check out a connection from the pool, which is how I interpreted step 2 in your question. If you set those variables only once when the connection is first created, then of course their values will be shared across multiple sessions during the lifetime of a connection.